# How do I direct some traffic to my Mifi and other traffic to my work wifi?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, mifi

My work blocks some personal sites and technical blogs.  I have a Mifi that I use it to check these sites.  I use the Windows Wifi picker to change between my work wifi and my personal mifi.  It gets annoying because I lose connection to some work sites when I am using my Mifi.  I'd like to seamlessly connect to my Mifi for Personal stuff and the work wifi for work stuff at the same time.

How do I direct some traffic to my Mifi and other traffic to my work wifi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first off you'd need 2 WiFi cards in the computer - one to connect to the WiFi and one to connect to the MiFi.

Then you'd need some way of slpitting the traffic.  If you know the IP addresses of the sites you want to get to you can just set up some static routes in windows.

Comment: In addition to the wireless adapter, I have a ethernet port that I can use for work.  I've been using the wifi, but only because it was more convenient.

Comment: I'm reading about static routes in windows.  It would be tough to specify every Internet IP I'd want to access, but it would be easy for work.  There's only 10 or so IPs that I'd have to add.

Comment: Specify work traffic as static routes and the default route to mifi perhaps?

Comment: I can already tell that I'm immediately in over my head with this routing.  Do you know of any tool (free or not) that could do this routing for me?